# Set value to a field in LINQ with logical expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm making a program for teacher to control students' practice lessons.
I need to set value like "Has report" if field has anything and "No report" if field is null or empty.

I have the following code:

C#

```
var record = from results in _context.Results
                             join students in _context.Students on results.Student_Id equals students.Id
                             join practice in _context.Practice on results.Theme_Id equals practice.Id
                             join gr in _context.Groups on students.Group_Id equals gr.Id
                             where gr.Title == group_selected
                             select new
                             {
                                 Theme = practice.Title,
                                 Student = students.Name,
                                 Report = results.File.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "No report" : "Has report"
                             };
```

But it gives me error:

> "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException" in
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll Error message: Undefined
> data. This method or property cannot be called for null values.

Please, help :)

Comment: What is `results.File` type? `string`? And what is your DBMS? SQL-Server, MySQL?

Comment: the variable 'record' returns this error? or results.File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off the assumption that results.File is a nullable NCHAR/ NVARCHAR in a Sql Server, in the null case, you would be doing DBNull.IsNullOrWhitespace(). This is not a defined extension method of DBNull.

I would write this null check as:

```
Report = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(results.File as string) ? "No report" : "Has report"
```

I hope this fixes the issue